# Nosetest including unwanted parent directories

Tags: python, nose

I'm trying to limit nosetests to a specific directory, however during the test run it's including the parent directories of the dir I'm targetting and in doing so throws errors.

Here's the key elements of output from the test run:

```
nose.importer: DEBUG: Add path /projects/myproject/myproject/specs
nose.importer: DEBUG: Add path /projects/myproject/myproject
nose.importer: DEBUG: Add path /projects/myproject
nose.importer: DEBUG: insert /projects/myproject into sys.path
```

I'm using `buildout` with `pbp.recipe.noserunner`. Here's the relevant `/projects/myproject/buildout.cfg` section:

```
[specs]
recipe = pbp.recipe.noserunner
eggs =
    pbp.recipe.noserunner
    ${buildout:eggs}
    figleaf
    pinocchio
working-directory = 
    myproject/specs
defaults =
    -vvv
    --exe
    --include ^(it|ensure|must|should|specs?|examples?)
    --include (specs?(.py)?|examples?(.py)?)$
    --with-spec
    --spec-color
```

I've also tried setting `where=myproject/specs` as one of the `defaults` parameters to help limit the import but still no joy.

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

**Edit:**

I've tried to `--exclude` the parent directories but no joy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that you are expecting the following behavior.

```
nose.importer: DEBUG: Add path /projects/myproject
nose.importer: DEBUG: insert /projects/myproject into sys.path
```

Why not try a `--match` or an `--exclude` pattern to restrict the tests set ?

Try:

```
--exclude myproject/myproject
```

I check the source code of nose.importer : nose recursivly add_path the parents packages of specs.
I think that you cannot bypass this unless you create a specific importer... 
I do not not know if this is possible this the nose API.

```
def add_path(path, config=None):
    """Ensure that the path, or the root of the current package (if
    path is in a package), is in sys.path.
    """

    # FIXME add any src-looking dirs seen too... need to get config for that

    log.debug('Add path %s' % path)    
    if not path:
        return []
    added = []
    parent = os.path.dirname(path)
    if (parent
        and os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, '__init__.py'))):
        added.extend(add_path(parent, config))
    elif not path in sys.path:
        log.debug("insert %s into sys.path", path)
        sys.path.insert(0, path)
        added.append(path)
    if config and config.srcDirs:
        for dirname in config.srcDirs:
            dirpath = os.path.join(path, dirname)
            if os.path.isdir(dirpath):
                sys.path.insert(0, dirpath)
                added.append(dirpath)
    return added


def remove_path(path):
    log.debug('Remove path %s' % path)
    if path in sys.path:
        sys.path.remove(path)
```

Comment: Thanks; I should've realized the best way to investigate is to read the source!

Comment: So then, make sure you don't have a `__init__.py` (or  `__init__.pyc`) where it's not required, right?