# Specially named directories using nosetests

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, nose, nosetests

Does `nosetests` treat directories with certain names differently?  Is a `src` directory special?

If I have a project whose source directory is named `src`, `nosetests` seems to work fine.  However, if the directory is named anything else, `nosetests` reports a bunch of import errors.

Here's what I did:

1. run tests

   ```
   ~/src$ nosetests
   ..
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

   OK
   ```
2. rename directory

   ```
   ~/src$ cd ..
   ~/$ mv src/ src2
   ```
3. rerun tests

   ```
   ~/$ cd src2
   ~/src2$ nosetests
   E
   ======================================================================
   ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named **whatever**)
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   ... etc. ...
       import **whatever**
   ImportError: No module named **whatever**

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 1 test in 0.001s

   FAILED (errors=1)
   ```

I wasn't able to find anything in the docs about this.

---

Example:  with this directory structure:

```
.
|-- a
|   |-- b.py
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.py
`-- test
    |-- a
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- testb.py
    `-- __init__.py
```

all `__init__.py` files are empty, the contents of `a/b.py` are:

```
y = 3
```

and of `test/a/testb.py`:

```
import a.b
import unittest as u


class TestB(u.TestCase):

    def test1(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test2(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

I can reliably reproduce this problem.  Running `nosetests -V` gives:

```
nosetests version 1.2.1
```

Comment: Should be smth simple. what imports do you have in your tests?

Comment: Quite a few, and the exact same imports in both cases.  Do you think a specific import could be causing a problem?  If so, why when the directory is not named `src`, but not when it is?

Comment: Well, I haven't reproduced it with one simple test case in the directory. Something in your tests (or smth that they import) requires `src` module to exist. Could you please just leave one simple test without any imports except `TestCase` class and try the same thing again?

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev I've added an example.  There's no mention of `src` anywhere in it, though.  I'm really stumped.  :(

Comment: I've created mentioned directory structure locally and yes, I've reproduced it. Interesting fact: if you remove `__init__.py` from the root dir - it'll work.

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev wow, that's blowing my mind!  I have no idea why it works that way.  Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe no, I haven't figured out why this happens.  I think I ended up using a work-around that I didn't fully understand ... :(

Comment: @alecxe I honestly don't know what I did ... hopefully I'll figure it out again at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Quick solution is to remove `__init__.py` from the top level directory. Another option is to use relative imports, for your example: replace `import a.b` with `from ...a import b`.

The culprit of this mess and trickiness is [nose importer](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/importer.py).

If the directory you are running `nosetests` in, is a package, nose won't add it to `sys.path`, otherwise, it'll add it ([source](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/importer.py#L136)). Then, it goes up throw directory tree and applies recursively the same logic. Same thing for all affected files. This explains why it isn't working with `__init__.py` - root dir (`src2` in your case) wasn't in sys.path - that's why package `a` wasn't found.

But, the open question here is: why it worked the first time, with `src` folder? 
`src` folder is on sys.path in this case. May be there will be other answers or edits.

See related questions:

- [Python Nose Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073259/python-nose-import-error)
- [Nosetest including unwanted parent directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197940/nosetest-including-unwanted-parent-directories)
- [Python imports for tests using nose - what is best practice for imports of modules above current package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670275/python-imports-for-tests-using-nose-what-is-best-practice-for-imports-of-modul)

Comment: If I run nosetests from setup.py with setup.py nosetests, I'm getting this trouble from build/lib; build/lib/xxx has an __init__.py, and submodules of it don't work.